# Select only the UL child of a LI item

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to do something similiar to a tree-view (really simpler)..

This is my effort: (When I click the first "parent-item it goes ok and reveals his "son", but when I click the son, which is also a "parent-item", it toggles back..

So I want something like that `closest()` function but for childs instead of parents..

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav .parent-item').click(function () {
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

the html:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>Atividade Recente</li>
<li class="parent-item">Projetos</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="parent-item"><a href="#">Renavam</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Atividade Recente</li>
                <li>Conversação</li>
                <li>Tarefas</li>
                <li>Pessoa & Permissões</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Minhas atividades</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).find('ul').first();
```

It finds all 'ul's below the context and the first() method limits it to just the first one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav .parent-item').click(function () {
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
       $('#nav li:not(".parent-item")').click(function(){
         return false;
       });
    });
```

Comment: It is working as I intented, but when i click a inner <li> (last level) it toggles back it's parent ul

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is no function `child` but `children` &</s> <sup>(typo</sup> in <sub>the question)</sub>

You have to `return false;` at the end of the function, otherwise the click will be bubbled up from children to their parents, that's why it appears to you as if the parent is toggling:

```
$('#nav .parent-item').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

#### jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QHr2r/1/

Comment: The OP changed his question, it turns out `.child()` was a typo in his code sample.